# Nullable reference types in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, nullable

Part of the latest version of .NET compilers is nullable reference types where you can declare a string as a Nullable type to indicate whether you intend for it to be able to store a null value.

This site details how to get it working in C#, but there's no reference to VB.NET in it: [Tutorial: Migrate existing code with nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/upgrade-to-nullable-references)

I am trying to get this working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project using VB.NET, but I have been unable to.  How does one do this, or is this just available in C#?

Comment: As far as I know, it's a C#-only feature.

Comment: Keep on eye on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/getting-started/whats-new) to find out about changes.

Comment: Because Microsoft's strategy for .NET changed back in 2017. Strategy for C#:  `"We will keep growing C# to meet the evolving needs of developers and remain a state of the art programming language."` Strategy for Visual Basic: `"We will keep Visual Basic straightforward and approachable."` So C# will continue to improve and VB has already begun to stagnate. From [The .NET Language Strategy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-net-language-strategy/)

Comment: I thought `Dim X as Long?` indicated a Nullable type in VB.Net?

Comment: @AJD That's a nullable value type, not a nullable reference type.  Currently, in VB, as was always the case in C#, reference types are always nullable.  But, in C# 8, they are adding a compiler feature where you can force all reference type variables to always have a value, unless you explicitly declare them as nullable.